# How to resolve "azure.common.AzureHttpError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure"

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access the list of containers within the storage account in my azure through python azure libraries (BlockBlobService)

I used the sas token generated through the program as well as manually through the azure portal to access the blob storage. However, I get an error as show in the exception.

```py
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService,
    ContainerPermissions,
)

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name='storage_account_name', sas_token= 'sas_token_taken_from_azure/sas_token_generated_through_code')
blobs = block_blob_service.list_blobs(containerName)

#code  used to generate sas token

def get_sas_token():
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
    sas_token = blob_service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(container_name,ContainerPermissions.READ, datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
    return sas_token
```

```
azure.common.AzureHttpError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:5670884b-f01e-0021-52cb-6fc574000000
Time:2019-09-20T15:52:27.4366679Z</Message></Error>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error is because you have defined `Read` permission in your Shared Access Signature (SAS) and you're trying to list blobs.

For listing blobs, you would need `List` permission.

Please try by changing your SAS and have it include `List` permission and you will not get this error.

Comment: Thank you. I have created the sas token from the azure portal using shared access signature tab with allowed permissions checked for all options ( Read, Write, List, Add, Create, Updated, Process). Even with the sas token generated with these options, I am getting the same error.

Comment: My answer was based on the code you shared. Please share your SAS Token so that I can take a look.

Comment: I did try with the code as well by changing READ to LIST. However, I received the same error.

Comment: Please share your SAS token.

Comment: That error has disappeared now after I changed the ContainerPermission to LIST. Thank you so much